# Any way to do Visual Studio "project only" build from command line?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, command-line

```
devenv mysolution.sln /build "Release|Win32" /project myproject
```

When building from the command line, it seems I have the option of doing a `/build` or `/rebuild`, but no way of saying I want to do "project only" (i.e. not build or rebuild the specified project's dependencies as well). Does anyone know of a way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build only one project in a solution from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558080/build-only-one-project-in-a-solution-from-command-line)

Answer (score 21):

Depending on the structure of your build system, this may be what you're looking for:

```
msbuild /p:BuildProjectReferences=false project.proj
```

Comment: Is the BuildProjectReferences=false going to make a difference when we're only in the context of a project (not solution) file?

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me! :)  @Owen, yes it does if you have project references in your vcxproj file for example.

Answer (score 10):

[MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) is what you want

```
MSBuild.exe MyProject.proj /t:build
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `devenv`, use the genericized build tool instead:

```
vcbuild subproject.vcproj "release|win32"
```

Comment: Does vcbuild have any advantages or drawbacks compared to msbuild?

Comment: For C/C++ projects, msbuild actually runs vcbuild as a child process. So yes. And no. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN [How To: Build Specific Targets in Solutions with MSBuild.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171486.aspx):

```
msbuild foo.sln /t:proj1:Rebuild;folder_of_proj2\proj2:Clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I see from a bit of looking into `msbuild` that it can deal with a `.sln` file rather than a `.vcproj`; can this be accomplished that way instead of having to know the location of the `.vcproj`?

Let me take a step back. We have a big solution file and I want a script to do this:

1. Do a `/build` on the whole solution.
   (Sometimes some projects fail because `devenv` doesn't do quite as much building as necessary for the amount of change since the last build.)
2. For each project that fails, do a `/rebuild` on it.

When I get to step 2 all I know is the solution filename and the names (not filenames) of the projects that failed. I could easily `grep`/`awk`/whatever the `.sln` file to map from one to the other, but I'm curious if `msbuild` offers a way to do it directly.

(Ideally I could give `msbuild` the `.sln` and the names of *all* the projects to rebuild in a single command line, as it's a large file and takes a while to load. If that's not possible then the option of manually finding all the project filenames is probably better as loading the solution file every time would be most inefficient.)

Answer (score 0):

The following works well for building a single C++ project in VS2010:

```
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%"\\vsvars32.bat
msbuild /detailedsummary /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /t:build MY_ABSOLUTE_PATH.vcxproj
```

Sadly, you can't simply specify a project name and a solution file to build just that project (unless you add a special configuration to your project files perhaps).