# error MSB4057: The target "v8" does not exist in the project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, v8, arangodb, msbuild-target

I'm trying to build V8 as part of [ArangoDB](http://www.arangodb.com) using the official [build scripts](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/tree/devel/3rdParty) and following the official [Windows build instructions](https://docs.arangodb.com/cookbook/CompilingUnderWindows.html).

The compilation fails for all v8* targets (`v8-build.bat`):

```
msbuild All.sln /t:v8 /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
msbuild All.sln /t:v8_libbase /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
msbuild All.sln /t:v8_libplatform /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
```

> error MSB4057: The target "v8" does not exist in the project.

If I open the solution file in Visual Studio, it looks like this:

[image: All.sln]

I can build `v8`, `v8_libbase` and `v8_libplatform` just fine in VS.

- Windows 7 64bit
- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
- Cygwin 2.2.0
- cmake 3.3.1

Answer (score 9):

You can run

```
set MSBuildEmitSolution=1
msbuild All.sln /t:v8
```

Then search in the generated `All.sln.metaproj` file the exact target names (`<Target Name="">`) of all projects you want to build. `v8` can have a name like `_tools_\_gyp_\v8`. After that you can build projects

```
msbuild All.sln /t:"_tools_\_gyp_\v8" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
```

Comment: Thanks this helped perfectly. My Issue for other to know is that if your project is name "hello.world"  The msbuild target is actually "hello_world"

Comment: The replacement of "." with "_" got me too. Also there is no "Build" target only "Rebuild". e.g. /t:Hello_World:Rebuild

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to specify a target/project if it's in a solution folder is:

```
msbuild all.sln /t:PATH\TO\PROJECT
```

But in case of `(tools)` and `(gyp)` it's simply not possible, because `msbuild` can't handle parentheses in the target parameter `/t`.

So either remove `( )` and specify the path like `tools\gyp\v8`, or get rid of the solution folders entirely. If the solution is flat, `/t:v8` will work.

Unfortunately, both the wrapping of folder names with brackets as well as the generation of non-flat .sln are hardcoded in gyp, which generated my `all.sln`. There is no switch to control whether solution folders are created or not. It will create them if the target version of Visual Studio is known to support this kind of nesting.

Workaround: Force flat solution generation in gyp, see
https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/796d2d263db6271142d954c8c99b9dec0fbe75e9

Reported errors to Microsoft/msbuild and Google/gyp:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/157
- https://code.google.com/p/gyp/issues/detail?id=494

@dothebart and [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/47329931-0681-45c5-a3bb-444d2bf256f7/msbuild-do-not-see-project-target-of-the-solution-when-launched-from-command-line-vc-solution) helped me a lot to figure it out, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In VS2013 use

```
msbuild All.sln /p:Project=v8;Configuration=Release;Platform=x64
```

Comment: I hurried - it's rebuild all solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an option.