# VSO How to build a single solution in a Repository containing two xamarin.ios projects?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are using Visual Studio Team Services as our source repository and for Build and Release.

What I Want to do? I have a solution that contains two xamarin.ios projects and want to automate in Visual Studio Team Service(VSO), but in VSO we have only one Signing & Provisioning section which accept only one Certificate and provisioning profile but i have two xamarin.ios projects in one solution file, which have different identifiers i-e com.www.test and com.www.test1.

Can someone provide the steps I need to take in order to only build one of the projects in Solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the Xamarin.iOS Buildstep, there's an option to specify a solution, which defaults do `**/*.sln`.

You can try to just pick the `.proj` file of your first app there.

I'd personally create a second build definition then, with the exact same settings, except I pick the other `.proj` file then.

You can also just create a second Xamarin.iOS Build Step, but then you'd have to fiddle around with all the parameters in the following steps. Can not recommend.

If that doesn't work, then just create two extra solutions, of which one only contains the first iOS project, the other one only the second iOS project. Then just specify these in the build step.

Comment: Actually My Project Depends upon on some other projects like PCL,Network,DataBase etc
So i have resolved this by cloning existing solution file and remove the one project from previous solution and add it in cloning solution file which i have created later.

Comment: @HafizMohsin Can't you build a project in he solution? You also can specify /t argument. [specify project file of a solution using msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915636/specify-project-file-of-a-solution-using-msbuild)