# Jenkins array variable in environment tag/body

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to define an array of strings within the environment tag/body of the Jenkins pipeline. This doesn't seem to work; jenkins doesn't recognize the array.

Environment variable values must either be single quoted, double quoted, or function calls. @ line x, column y.
        myArray= [

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'Test'
    }

    environment {
        myArray = [
            "Item1",
            "Item2",
            "Item3"
        ]
    }
}
```

The next code seems to work, but I would like to have all fields/ settings in the environment tag.

```
def myArray = [
            "Item1",
            "Item2",
            "Item3"
        ]

pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'Test'
    }

    environment {
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to use an array as environment variable?

Comment: Would this not be better as a `param` than an `env`?

Answer (score 5):

> Environment variable values must either be single quoted, double quoted, or function calls.

You can define a function which will return your array.

```
def getArray(){
  return ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'Test'
    }

    environment {
      ARRAY=getArray()
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we make a dynamic object where we can add to the array later in a step script block?

Comment: I got it to work by adding def _myArrayName = [] before the pipeline. Later in the stage>step I had to use the array in a script block.

Comment: Note that this makes `ARRAY` in fact a string, literally `"['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']"`. `ARRAY.length()` will return 27, `ARRAY[0]` will return '[', etc.

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy hey, do you happen to know how to get rid of this "["? I got the same case

Answer (score 0):

Make a replacement in json, use the method groovy Eval.me. In the final json you will get an array.
Example:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'Test'
    }
    environment {
        Example="['test1','test2','test3']"
    }
    stages{
        stage ("example") {
            steps {
                script{
                    def json file = readJSON file: 'template.json'
                    jsonfile['key']['value'] = Eval.me(env.Example)
                }
    }
}
```