# What's the grammar for AzureDevOps `dotnet build` project path?How do I add more than one project for `dotnet build` project path?

Tags: azure-devops

As the title, we use `**/*.csproj` commonly for  `dotnet build` project path, it works greatly.
But we recently add a dotnet framework project, while we run our build on *nix build agent, we wanna exclude the dotnet framework projects or include the dotnet core projects only, but when I try to update the project path like `dotnet pack`, I meet the error below:

```
Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.
```

but the project path I defined works for `dotnet pack` project path, I'm so confused. Hope anyone would help.

project path I use:

```
Business/*.csproj;Models/*.csproj;
**/*.csproj;-FxModels/*.csproj;
```

issue from https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3981

Answer (score 2):

> What's the grammar for AzureDevOps `dotnet build` project path?

There is no special syntax for AzureDevOps `dotnet build` project path, it just use **relative path** and **wildcard**.

When we use the task `dotnet build` to build the project, we always the syntax `**/*.csproj` to include all the project in specify branch of the repos. Assuredly, we could also use full path to specify the one project. For example:

In the get source task of the pipeline, we set the `repos` and `branch`:

[image]

Then, go to the `repos` to get the relative path of the `.net core` project:

[image]

So, the relative path of the `.net core` project is `/NetCoreLibDemo/NetCoreLibDemo/NetCoreLibDemo.csproj`, if you want only build the .net core project only:

[image]

> How do I add more than one project for `dotnet build` project path?

You can specify more than one project for `dotnet build` project path by using `**/*.csproj` or specify the `.sln` file.

**However**, I have pointed out that if you are use the task **dotnet pack** rather than `dotnet build` for more than one projects, you can make a pattern negative by prefixing it with **`-:`**, like:

[image]

It works fine on my side, you can check if it works for you.

**Update:**

> as I mentioned above, dotnet pack projects grammer did not work for
>   dotnet build, so wanna a grammar for dotnet build, that's the point of
>   the question

The grammar **`-:`** is specify for **dotnet pack**. You could get it from states of the option:

[image]

[image]

**So,** just like I pointed above, if you want to specify more than one project for `dotnet build` project path by using `**/*.csproj` or specify the `.sln` file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: not so useful for me, everything you mentioned above I'd tried before, dotnet pack grammer is different from dotnet build, and `**/*.csproj` sometimes is not applicable

Comment: @WeihanLi, Thanks for your reply. I have test the prefixing `;-:` and it works fine on my side with dotnet pack task. If it not work for, could you please share the Path to csproj or nuspec file(s) to pack to me, BTW, do not use `**/*.csproj`,  try to use `ProjectA/NetCoreLibDemo/*.csproj;-:ProjectB/ProjectA/*.csproj` instead.

Comment: it works for `dotnet pack`, but I'm asking for grammer of `dotnet build` task not `dotnet pack`..., as I mentioned above, `dotnet pack` projects grammer did not work for `dotnet build`, so wanna a grammar for `dotnet build`, that's the point of the question

Comment: @WeihanLi, Got it. Indeed, The grammar `-:` is only specify for dotnet pack. if you want to specify more than one project for dotnet build project path by using `**/*.csproj` or specify the `.sln` file, check my updated answer for some more details.

Comment: sometimes `**/*.csproj` or `*.sln` is **not applicable**

Comment: @WeihanLi, If you have any issue when you use `**/*.csproj` or `*.sln`, you can open a new thread with details info. And on that case, you can use the MSBuild to build multiple projects, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915636/specify-project-file-of-a-solution-using-msbuild

Comment: thanks for your tracking and reply, but it seemed to be not so helpful, had you tried in practice? I'd changed the build step for cake build, it works greatly with cake build now.

Comment: @WeihanLi, Of course, many of my current pipeline build are set up this way **/*.csproj or  `.sln`. I'm not sure if this method doesn't work for you due to our pipleline or project settings. Since you have found the way to resolve this issue, you can share your solution with answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues

Comment: Yeah, `**/*.csproj` works in most of cases, while sometimes `**/*.csproj` may contain some projects I do not wanna build, in this case, can not use `**/*.csproj` and `*.sln`. I think the method I use(`cake`) has none business with azure devops, so I do not think it's a recommended answer for the problem.

Comment: @WeihanLi, If your final question is sometimes **/*.csproj may contain some projects I do not wanna build, using **/*.csproj and *.sln should not work for you. In this case, you can use Msbuild to build it or you can add one more build tasks to build the multiple projects you want.

Comment: Thanks @leo-liu-msft, I feel it's strange to set up more than one build steps for `dotnet build`, so I question for the grammar for build multi projects like `dotnet pack`, from the answers above you supplied, seemed not support for now. Thanks so much for your effort