# Project layout for small, shared C# classes

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm writing plugins (i.e. .Net 4 libraries with a special entry point) for a .Net framework application, but I also want to expose the functionality as self-contained CLI executable.

The current directory layout looks like this:

```
Directory.build.props // shared configuration, e.g. author name, project name
FooPlugin/FooPlugin.cs
Foo/FooPlugin/FooPlugin.csproj
Foo/FooLib/FooLib.cs
Foo/FooLib/FooLib.csproj
Foo/FooExe/FooExe.cs
Foo/FooExe/FooExe.csproj
Bar/BarPlugin/…
```

`FooLib` is a .Net Standard 2.0 library with the entire functionality in `FooLib.cs`, `FooPlugin` is a .Net 4.8 library with the entry point for the plugin `FooPlugin.cs` and `FooExe` is a .Net Core executable with a CLI wrapper for `FooLib` in `FooExe.cs`. So far, so good.

I have two major problems with this approach:

1. `FooPlugin` depends on several application specific Windows-only assemblies so I can't just `dotnet build` from the root directory, because msbuild tries to build `FooPlugin` as well and I haven't figured out how to conditionally exclude subprojects from the solution file.
2. Each plugin (and CLI app) has two files (`FooPlugin.dll` and `FooLib.dll` / `FooExe.dll` and `FooLib`.dll`) which in itself isn't that bad, but my users ignore` FooLib.dll`and then complain.`ILMerge` looks promising, but its configuration is a lot more complicated than the entire remaining build configuration combined.

In CMake, I'd just write

```
add_library(FooLib STATIC FooLib.cpp)
add_library(FooPlugin SHARED FooPlugin.cpp)
target_link_libraries(FooPlugin PRIVATE FooLib)
add_executable(FooExe SHARED FooExe.cpp)
target_link_libraries(FooExe PRIVATE FooLib)
```

and have `FooLib` merged into both `FooPlugin.dll` and `FooExe.exe`.

I already thought about putting symlinks to the (few) source files in `FooLib` into `FooPlugin` and `FooExe`, but the support for symlinks on Windows isn't that good yet.

Can I define targets in msbuild to be merged into assemblies automatically?

Answer (score 1):

A fairly trivial solution would be to just create multiple solution files that each contain some of the projects.

For a more competent solution I would take a look at [Cake](https://cakebuild.net/) or [Fake](https://fake.build/). I have used neither, but they seem to be the most popular build systems on the .net platform.

You can also use the target switch for msBuild to [build a specific project in a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915636/specify-project-file-of-a-solution-using-msbuild).