# publishing asp.net web application using msbuild

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, msbuild

I am new to ASP.NET web application. I created an **ASP.NET web application (.NET framework) using c#** and wrote some api's and ran it from visual studio. But now I want to Publish my application to a local folder using the command line. I could not find a workable command so please help.

Comment: https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/publishing/iis.html

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya actually I wanted a command which I could run in the console.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915636/specify-project-file-of-a-solution-using-msbuild

Comment: Does this answer your question? [specify project file of a solution using msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915636/specify-project-file-of-a-solution-using-msbuild)

Comment: The link shows me how to build using msbuild but I want to publish my asp.net web application

Comment: The following may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097489/how-to-publish-web-with-msbuild