# How to specify project to build in Azure DevOps VSBuild task?

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have this yaml pipeline in Azure DevOps:

```
variables:
  solution: 'fph.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- xxxx

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /t:FPH_Api\FPH_Api_csproj;Rebuild'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

The solution contain multiple projects and I am hoping that by providing `DesktopBuildPackageLocation` parameter and target parameter `FPH_Api\FPH_Api_csproj;Rebuild`, VSBuild will rebuild my web api project (so will rebuild other referenced projects as well) and then automatically zip the build into `webapp.zip`.

However, I got this error:

> FPH_Api\FPH_Api_csproj" does not exist in the project.

I replaced the dots in `FPH.API\FPH.api.csproj` with underscores as dot is a forbidden character and tried several combinations like `FPH_Api\FPH_Api` or `FPH_Api`, but got the same error message.

Detail error shows this:

```
Project "D:\a\1\s\fph.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\FPH.Api\FPH.Api.csproj" (2) on node 1 (FPH_Api\FPH_Api_csproj target(s)).
D:\a\1\s\FPH.Api\FPH.Api.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "FPH_Api\FPH_Api_csproj" does not exist in the project.
Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\FPH.Api\FPH.Api.csproj" (FPH_Api\FPH_Api_csproj target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

Seems the way I am doing things is not correct. So is it possible to use the VSBuild task to build a project in a solution and automatically zip the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue in my pipeline.

[image]

To solve this issue, you could define the target to folder level instead of csproj file level.

For example:

File structure：(csproj file is under Sample.WebAPI folder)

[image]

argument:   `/t:Sample_WebApi:Rebuild`

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"   /t:Sample_WebApi:Rebuild'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

For more info, you could refer to this doc about [How to: Build specific targets in solutions by using MSBuild.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 2):

I realise that this is an old question but I have just been through similar pain trying to build a specific project from my solution using the [msbuild targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022#switches) argument. The answer was buried in this stack overflow thread [specify project file of a solution using msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19534376/21192597) but it still took me a while to work out.

The msbuild /t parameter does not want file path and file name. Instead it requires the solution folder structure and the name of the project.

1. Optional: solution folder structure
2. Project name
3. wrapped in double quotes if there are any spaces in the parameter
4. Periods replaced with underscores.

For example if I have added FPH.Api project within a second level solution folder (e.g. Top Level > Second Level > FPH.Api) then I will see something like this in the .SLN file

```
Project("{guid}") = "Top Level", "Top Level", "{guid}"
EndProject
Project("{guid}") = "Second Level", "Second Level", "{guid}"
EndProject
Project("{guid}") = "FPH.Api", "FPH.Api\FPH.Api.csproj", "{guid}"
EndProject
```

In this case you would construct the /t parameter value as:

```
/t:"Top Level\Second Level\FPH_Api"
```

I hope that is helpful.

Comment: you made me a helpful birthday present, thx

Answer (score 0):

this was me me the easiest solution:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: "Build API"
  inputs:
    solution: '**/yourAPI.csproj'
    arguments.....
```