Azure pipelin: how to publish ASP.NET MVC app in normal file structure
I have a solution with multiple projects. I want to obtain (in artifacts) project UserUi.csproj, which is an ASP.NET MVC app (with references to other libraries inside the solution), ready to be copied to a server.
By running this yml:
trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

variables:
  solution: "**/*.sln"
  buildPlatform: "Any CPU"
  buildConfiguration: "Release"

steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: "$(solution)"

  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: "$(solution)"
      msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem  /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\UserUi"'
      platform: "$(buildPlatform)"
      configuration: "$(buildConfiguration)"

  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      platform: "$(buildPlatform)"
      configuration: "$(buildConfiguration)"

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\UserUi'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'

I'm getting weird "deploy" files, and UserUi.deploy.zip file which contains proper files, but in a path:
UserUi.zip\Content\D_C\a\1\s\4. SampleLayer\UserUi\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp

Why is that? How can I get just one zip (or normal folder) with PackageTmp contents inside?
I will need to publish this (copy to specified folder) artifacts by using Azure agent installed on server, but with this structure I can't.

I can reproduce the same situation when using the VSBuild and same arguments.

How can i just have a one zip (or normal folder) with PackageTmp contents inside?

To meet your requirement, you can add the following vsbuild argument to directly put the outputs to artifacts folder:
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\\UserUi"

In this case, the PackageTmp contents inside will show in a normal folder.
Update:

i'm getting all of the projects - except the UserUi... i need to have file structure like Bin, Content, fonts, Scripts, Views, favicon.ico, Global.asax, Web.config

To solve this issue, we need to remove the VSBuild argument: /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True. Then it will add the required files to the artifacts.
VSbuild argument:
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\\UserUi"

YAML sample:
trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

variables:
  solution: "**/*.sln"
  buildPlatform: "Any CPU"
  buildConfiguration: "Release"

steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: "$(solution)"

  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: "$(solution)"
      msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\\UserUi"'
      platform: "$(buildPlatform)"
      configuration: "$(buildConfiguration)"

  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      platform: "$(buildPlatform)"
      configuration: "$(buildConfiguration)"

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\UserUi'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'

Result: it will contain the bin ,fonts, scripts and other files.


Hi. Now i'm getting all of the projects - except the UserUi... And whats more, i need to have file structure like Bin, Content, fonts, Scripts, Views, favicon.ico, Global.asax, Web.config - not the dll files

@guidempty I can fully understand your requirement and issue now. Please refer to my updated answer. We can remove the /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True vsbuild argument and keep using the argument from my answer. In this case, it will generate the required files and folders in artifacts.

On the other hand, if you only want to build one of the projects , you can use the vsbuild argument: /t:projectname to define it. Refer to this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68916280/20645100

thanks mate, it have worked! Cheers

Try simplifying your VSBuild task.  Then use a CopyFiles task to organize only the files you want to deploy from your build.  Here is a generic example:
- task: VSBuild@1
displayName: 'VS Build'
inputs:
solution: '**\$(ProjectName).csproj'
platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
clean: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
displayName: 'Copy files to staging directory'
inputs:
SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
Contents: |
    $(ProjectName)\App_Data\**
    $(ProjectName)\bin\**
    $(ProjectName)\appSettings.config
    $(ProjectName)\Web.config
    $(ProjectName)\Web.$(BuildConfiguration).config
TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
CleanTargetFolder: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
inputs:
PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

This one builds only one web project out of my whole solution.  But you could build the whole solution too.
Or, you can also try applying only one of your msbuildargs at a time and viewing the output to see if you can eliminate the one making the crazy file structures.
You can also add the publishLocation attribute to your PublishArtifacts step to write the PathtoPublish contents directly to another file location without having to retrieve them from your artifacts.

Hi, thanks for answer. Im getting error:
##[error]Solution not found using search pattern 'D:\a\1\s**$UserUi.csproj'.
With code You provided.

What does your yml line for "solution:" look like?  it reading stars and the $ as actual text values seems off.
