# Is there a way to include an existing Visual Studio project (vcproj) in a qmake .pro file?

Tags: build, qmake

Using qmake and pro files I am generating multiple project solutions which depend on each other. For example:

A <- B <- C where "->" means "depends on". I also have a project D which depends on both B and C.

Assuming I already generated solution/project files for project A and know where they are located, is there any way to tell qmake to include those existing .vcproj files in the solution file for project B? I suppose I'm looking for a one-click build config using qmake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QMake's custom target features](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets) to add a build step that can run a custom command. Then for the custom command, use the [MSBuild command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123632/any-way-to-do-visual-studio-project-only-build-from-command-line) to build the Visual Studio projects. The exact usage will vary depending on your needs, but [this answer might be a good starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083441/how-to-add-pre-build-step-in-qmake-qtcreator).